# Querying Dbpedia by DBO - SPARQL

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am trying to extract the manufacturer section of this dbpedia page `http://dbpedia.org/page/Diageo`. However my SPARQL query returns nothing. Yet I can return most other values on the page, such as keyPersons which has the exact same layout.

```
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT ?label
WHERE { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Diageo>
        dbpedia-owl:keyPerson ?label }
```

---

```
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT ?label
WHERE { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Diageo>
        dbpedia-owl:manufacturer ?label }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `^dbo:manufacturer` instead of `dbo:manufacturer`. Or `?variable dbo:manufacturer dbr:Diageo` instead of `dbr:Diageo dbo:manufacturer ?variable`.

Comment: Nope, no luck. Thank you for your comment though, appreciate it!

Comment: What means "no luck"?! Stanislav is right, `SELECT ?label
WHERE { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Diageo>
        ^dbo:manufacturer ?label }`

Comment: Ah yeah, not sure what I did! Thanks guys. Feel free to answer it and i'll mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In DBpedia, an entity page displays statements in which an entity may be not only a subject, but also an object. In the latter case, respective property appears as "*is ... of*".

Conversely, [the page](http://dbpedia.org/page/Diageo) you have linked to says that `dbr:Diageo` *is* `dbo:manufacturer` *of* `dbr:Johnnie_Walker` etc. This means that `dbr:Johnnie_Walker dbo:manufacturer dbr:Diageo` holds, not that `dbr:Diageo dbo:manufacturer dbr:Johnnie_Walker` does.

By the way, `rdfs:range` of `dbo:manufacturer` [is](http://dbpedia.org/ontology/manufacturer) `dbo:Organization`.

Thus, you should looking for triples that match reversed pattern:

```
SELECT * WHERE { ?variable dbo:manufacturer ?dbr:Diageo . }
```

Or, using [property paths](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#propertypaths):

```
SELECT * WHERE { dbr:Diageo ^dbo:manufacturer ?variable . }
```

[Try it on DBpedia](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=SELECT+*+WHERE+%7B+dbr%3ADiageo+%5Edbo%3Amanufacturer+%3Fvariable+.+%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=+Run+Query+)