# Selecting variable in form of "is dbp:variable of" in SPARQL

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am trying to select what is some country (for example India) northeast of from DBPedia using SPARQL. I am using query:

```
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
SELECT  ?northeast ?ne
WHERE {
    OPTIONAL {<http://dbpedia.org/resource/India> dbp:northeast ?northeast }
.   OPTIONAL {?northeast foaf:name ?ne}
}
```

where in variable dbp:northeast should be

> Comilla_Division, Rangpur_Division

but it selects long list of other things. I figured problem might be that in DBPedia is that variable in this syntax: "is dbp:northeast of".

Does someone know how to formulate query for that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for "is ... of", see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49153616/7879193). Your query should be:

```sql
SELECT ?northeast ?ne WHERE {
    ?northeast dbp:northeast dbr:India 
    OPTIONAL {?northeast foaf:name ?ne}
}
```

[Try it!](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=SELECT+%3Fnortheast+%3Fne+WHERE+%7B%0D%0A++++%3Fnortheast+dbp%3Anortheast+dbr%3AIndia+%0D%0A++++OPTIONAL+%7B%3Fnortheast+foaf%3Aname+%3Fne%7D%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=+Run+Query+)

or

```sql
SELECT ?northeast ?ne WHERE {
    VALUES (?country) {(dbr:India)}
    ?country ^dbp:northeast ?northeast; rdfs:label ?ne.
    FILTER (lang(?ne) = "en") .
}
```

[Try it!](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=SELECT+%3Fnortheast+%3Fne+WHERE+%7B%0D%0A++++VALUES+%28%3Fcountry%29+%7B%28dbr%3AIndia%29%7D%0D%0A++++%3Fcountry+%5Edbp%3Anortheast+%3Fnortheast+%3B%0D%0A++++++++++++++rdfs%3Alabel+++++%3Fne+.%0D%0A++++FILTER+%28lang%28%3Fne%29+%3D+%22en%22%29+.%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=+Run+Query+)

---

It is much more interesting, why "long list of other things" is returned instead of empty resultset.

From [In SPARQL, Order Matters](https://wiki.blazegraph.com/wiki/index.php/SPARQL_Order_Matters#A_Simple_Example):

> SPARQL evaluation starts out over the so-called “empty mapping” (also called “universal mapping”): [if] the OPTIONAL block is not able to retrieve any results, and given the semantics of OPTIONAL, this step simply retains the empty mapping.

In general, never start with `OPTIONAL`.

Comment: But it doesnt work for another countries. For example 

SELECT ?south ?ne WHERE {
    ?south dbp:south dbr:Finland
    OPTIONAL {?south foaf:name ?ne}
}

For Finland it doesnt return but there is dpb:south in Finland.

Comment: There is `dbo:south`, but there isn't ***is*** `dbo:south` ***of***, please read the linked answer carefully.