# SPARQL cannot query "is of" relationship

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am querying some features like:

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
select ?field where { 
  dbpedia:Jeffrey_Karp dbo:field ?field
}
```

This return the content correctly. But if I query some feature in the form "is ** of", the query will return null， though the field exists. Here is the query:

```
select ?studentof where { 
  dbpedia:Jeffrey_Karp dbo:notableStudent ?studentof
}
```

[image: Image that shows feature]

Comment: Just add `^` before `dbo:notableStudent`. Possible duplicate of [Querying Dbpedia by DBO - SPARQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49152535/querying-dbpedia-by-dbo-sparql)

Comment: "is" denotes the inverse direction, thus, switch subject and object in the triple pattern. Or as Stanislav suggested, use the SPARQL 1.1 shortcut via property path inverse `^`

Comment: This is also interesting that `dbr:Jeffrey_Karp dbp:notableStudents ...`, whereas `dbr:Robert_S._Langer dbo:notableStudent ...`.